# How to Use Data From a FITS File Directly (Not converting it to a text file)

Tags: python, fits, pyfits

I have a bunch of values written in a FITS file. There's like 320,000 points in each column... The columns that I need are 3 columns called, detx, dety, and energy. 
I need to use this data for my program. 
I know how to convert this FITS file into a txt file (example shown below) and then use the data, but how can I use the data directly? For example,how could I get the data from this FITS file, and then print it out in python?

Here's an example of how to convert the fits file into a text file:

```
from astropy.io import fits
#This is what the file is called
hdulist = fits.open('acisf02149N003_evt2.fits.gz')
hdulist.info()
tbdata = hdulist[1].data

#This prints it out into a text file
f=open('ChandraXraysources.txt','w+')

#This chooses only the detx, dety, and energy columns I was talking about
detxvect=tbdata.field('detx')
detyvect=tbdata.field('dety')
detzvect=tbdata.field('energy')

#This lists at the top of the text file the names of each column 
f.write('Chandra X-ray source, RA(x),dec(y),energy  \r\n')

for i in range(len(detxvect)):
    f.write('%e  %e  %e\r\n' %(detxvect[i],detyvect[i],detzvect[i]))

print(detxvect[0])
```

Comment: Could you, please, post the result of `hdulist.info()` and maybe even `print(type(tbdata))`.

Comment: _"I know how to convert this FITS file into a txt file (example shown below) and then use the data, but how can I use the data directly? For example,how could I get the data from this FITS file, and then print it out in python?"_ Your question is very confusing with regard to what are you exactly asking. Specifically, in your example you already illustrate how to use table data directly: your `f.write('%e  %e  %e\r\n' %(detxvect[i],detyvect[i],detzvect[i]))` statement in the loop illustrates this.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the data directly"?

Comment: Perhaps you just need to learn how to use Numpy in an interactive Python environment (e.g. IPython)?

Answer (score 0):

To use the data directly you can try

```
import os, glob
from astropy.io import fits, ascii

# Open all files and store them into a list
files = glob.glob(dir + '*.fits')
hdu_lst = [fits.open(dir + fi) for fi in files]

#You choose the columns you'll be using
detx = [hdi[0].header['DETX'] for hdi in hdu_lst]
dety = [hdi[0].header['DETY'] for hdi in hdu_lst]
energy = [hdi[0].header['ENERGY'] for hdi in hdu_lst]

# You can also write a file with all the filenames
ascii.write([files, detx,dety,energy],'table.dat',names=(['Filename','DETX','DETY','ENERGY']),format = 'fixed_width',delimiter = '|',bookend =   True,overwrite = True)

#Close all files at end
[hdi.close for hdi in hdu_lst]
```

Comment: This gives some idea of how to write data to an ASCII file, yes, but "use the data directly" is not defined by the OP and I don't see how this provides that either.

Answer (score 0):

> *I know how to convert this FITS file into a txt file (example shown below) and then use the data, but how can I use the data directly? For example,how could I get the data from this FITS file, and then print it out in python?*

Your question is very confusing with regard to what are you exactly asking. Specifically, in your example you already illustrate how to use table data directly: your

```
f.write('%e  %e  %e\r\n' %(detxvect[i],detyvect[i],detzvect[i]))
```

statement in the loop illustrates this.

That is, just use `detxvect`, `detyvect`, `detzvect` as you would use any `numpy` 1D array.